# Using aspnet_regsql.exe on a MySQL server intance

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Has anybody had any success doing this?

I am referring to the following documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Here is my output:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regsql.exe -S localhost -U
root -P pwd -d aspnetdb -A all
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET SQL Registration Tool version 4.0.30319.18408
Administrative utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET features on a SQL server
.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

It worked fine last time I used it on a MSSQL Sever instance.

Start adding the following features:
Membership
Profile
RoleManager
Personalization
SqlWebEventProvider

.................
An error has occurred. Details of the exception:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a conne
ction to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that
 the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a conne
ction to SQL Server)

Worked fine when I used it on a MSSQL server.

Comment: What in this documentation makes you think you can use this tool with anything but SQL Server?

Comment: I was originally referring to this documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html

Comment: For now I don't need an aspnet application just the db and the membership api on the back end possibly within a RPC- creating an aspnet application just to have a aspnetdb available on mysql seems rather tedious. I should add the term SQL Server seems rather vague.

Comment: SQL Server is the name of the Microsoft database product (Microsoft SQL Server) if we have to be precise. I do not think this particular tool works with anything but SQL Server. The documentation on the MySQL website refers to a different implementation of Membership Provider. It seems like the library can create the database on its own.